# How to get data-attribute value of paper-card from on-tap event

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

The goal is to get the value of the `data-id`-attribute of the `paper-card` in the method `openForm` called from the `ontap` event.

Neither of the two attempts down work. Here is my code:

```
<div class="layout horizontal wrap">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{itemList}}">
    <paper-card on-tap="openForm" data-id="{{item.id}}">
        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        <paper-item>
            <iron-icon class="big" src$="{{setIcon(item)}}"></iron-icon>
            <paper-item-body two-line>
                <div>{{item.fullNameRev}}</div>
                <div secondary style$="{{color(item.groupColor)}}">{{item.group}}</div>
            </paper-item-body>
        </paper-item>
        </paper-card>
    </template>
</div>
```

---

```
Polymer({
        is : "my-element",
        openForm: function(e) {
                e.srcElement.getAttribute("data-id"); // does not work
                e.target.getAttribute("data-id"); // neither works
        },
        color: function(c) {
            return "color:" + c;
        }
});
```

Comment: outside of polymer, e.currentTarget._selection.selection[0]._parent_item.id  may work? ie in a normal window listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for can be found here:
 [Handling events in dom-repeat templates](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#handling-events)

Explains it better than I can, but I guess in short it creates a 'model' accessible to e.model.item.data-id for whichever paper-card sends the event. I think your code will look something along the lines of:

```
Polymer({
    is : "my-element",
    openForm: function(e) {
            var model = e.model
            model.item.id, //think this will be the value
    color: function(c) {
        return "color:" + c;
    }
});
```